# Flajolet et al analytic combinatorics integral

Tags: integration, combinatorics, graph-theory, lagrange-inversion

I am reading Flajolet et al. [Airy Phenomena and Analytic Combinatorics of Connected Graphs](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r34). 2004.

We are presented with the following integral

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\exp\left(-\frac 12 z^2+xe^{iz\sqrt{\log q}}\right)dz
\end{equation}

The integral is not carried out in closed form, but does have asymptotic results. I am wondering if a closed form solution exists in the near 20 years since this paper was published?

Comment: Closed form in terms of what? In the stationary phase analysis I assume they do there's nothing really stopping you from including all the terms in the power series expansion of the exponential, so in principle there is an exact expression to be had, it's just not very nice or useful, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I suppose by closed form I meant a "nice or useful" formula, rather than, as you say, truncating the expansion.

Comment: I could be wrong, but spontaneously I would be surprised if there's a nice expression for this, then. An asymptotic seems very nice to me though, since it's possible to truncate further out you can get better control of the secondary etc. terms.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe I am being too picky! Thank you for your thoughts.